# FileWriter cutting data in .csv file

Tags: excel, csv, groovy, printwriter

I have a little problem which I am currently trying to resolve. I have a List full of data points (around 10000 points). I am trying to write all these points to a .csv file. The two first lines are working perfectly fine but at the end of the second one i have this :

> ...,7691,8441,9368,10118,10

and the next line begins with :

> 04,10118,9368,8441,...

First question is when does Excel cut data ? Given that all the data has been saved into one cell per line, it has to be that each excel cell has a limit of data you can put into.

Second question is how to avoid it to happen ? I have already tried with BufferedWriter, writer.append(), writer.flush() at the end of the copying but it didn't do anything.

Here is the code (***it is groovy, do not bother about missing ';' and println without ()***):

```
final PrintWriter writer
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8")

            //Do not bother about that line
            List<Integer> dataPoints = context.getComponents().get("sig_graph").getDataPoints()

            while (count < dataPoints.size - 1) {
                writer.flush()
                println dataPoints.get(count)
                writer.write(String.valueOf(dataPoints.get(count)) + ',')
                count++
            }
            writer.write(String.valueOf(dataPoints.get(count)))
            writer.close()
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Comment: `println dataPoints.get(count)` is not Java. Is that supposed to be a comment? Also, why are all the data written into one line?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Sorry, just added that it is groovy. It is java but just without ';' and little differences. It is written into one line for exporting reasons.

Comment: I'm asking because your question says things like "the first two lines", but I only see one line here.

Comment: @RealSkeptic oh yes ! sorry again, i can provide you all the data, it is just a bit long. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TGDcMmj6JoWgqrpig3iDgfw4mWZMMbmbhHRRiJZTU40/edit?usp=sharing here is a google sheet with the data

Comment: This is the same, but more groovy... `file.withWriter('UTF-8') { w -> w.write context.components.get('sig_graph').dataPoints.join(',') }`  does it give the same result?

Comment: @tim_yates : Tried with your code cample but it gave the same result : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TGDcMmj6JoWgqrpig3iDgfw4mWZMMbmbhHRRiJZTU40/edit#gid=0

Comment: I'm really not sure what your problem is. You get all the data in one cell. It wraps in display but it's still in one cell. Where are the "lines" that you are talking about?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Problem is solved. Excel cuts data after a certain point. Opening the file with notepad++ gives the right amount of data needed and everything seems correct. There are lines into the cell because excel cannot exceed 254 characters per line per cell +(\n that it adds). So it cuts those in lines, and gives a crappy result.

Comment: Question is, why are you putting all the data into one cell? Why not read it as a CSV, one value into each cell?

Comment: @RealSkeptic : because i was dumb enough to put a comma instead of a semicolon as a separator, my colleague pointed it out yesterday. Still, the amount of data Excel can take is 10000 columns. Might be a little bit short. Gotta arrange that somehow. Thanks for the help with tim_yates